# On the misuse of two sample test: How to report difference in entire "populations"

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, group-differences, exploratory-data-analysis

I have the following understanding: Two (or more) sample tests are only required if conclusion should be drawn about a population based on observed samples (typically much smaller than the population).

If I observe the entire population, e.g. quality (numeric) of each product produced in two or more factories, then this approach does not apply. I could directly compare the population means but this does not provide information how important/large (not significant! ) the difference is. One could compare the difference to the **std** (of either of the populations). To circumvent choosing one standard deviation of one population one could consider a joint standard deviation of the combined population (what if some factories are much larger than others). (standard deviation could be replaced by IQR or similar). This can be extended to multiple products produced in multiple factories.

What is the best way to present these comparisons? What is the best reference to show that no significance test is required (pretty obvious to me).

Comment: What about a t-test do you think gives you an indication of how important/large the difference is? (That's not what the p-value means!)

Comment: I don't see the logic here as to why inference is not needed. If you observed the same type of data in a different time period, you would get different data, even assuming the processes are stable and "in control". With inference, you can ask questions about the underlying processes. In the population framework, you cannot.

Comment: Then your statement are about a hypothetical generative process.

Comment: Significance tests are never "required". They address a specific question, and if this question is not of interest, they are not needed, not in your situation, not in others. Not sure what you mean by "best way to present these comparisons"; obviously all visual methods and descriptive statistics are at your disposal. It all depends on what information is relevant in your situation. (In fact, there are situations in which interpreting the data as sample from a hypothetical generating process, see above, makes some sense, then a test can make sense, too.)

Comment: **This question does not have a statistical answer,** because the issue of "importance" concerns what the difference in averages means for the manufacturer.  It could be anywhere from inconsequential to deadly.  As an example of the first, a difference in sugar content of candies could translate to no discernible effect on quality and not change the manufacturing cost. As an example of the second, a difference in activity of a drug could make the product kill people.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the full population, you are (indeed) in a position where you do not need to make inference. So, you « simply » need to analyse the figures. Using "side-to-side" boxplots can be a good start to understand better your data.

Simple example in R

```
factory1 <- c(50,55,52,57,53,2,125,70,74,40,45,48,115,1,56,86,30,69,36)
factory2 <- c(50,55,52,57,53,2,125,70,74,40,45,48,145,1,56,86,30,69,36,28,27,29,24,31,29,85,87,83,89,84,85,84)
factory3 <- c(50,55,52,57,53,2,125,70,74,40,45,48,145,1,56,86,30,69,36,85,87,83,89,84,85,84,120,115,110,109,133,125,129,160,123)
boxplot(factory1, factory2, factory3, names=c("Factory 1","Factory 2", "Factory 3"), col=c("#f68e1f","#00adef", "#ec008b"))
```

[image]

You might also be interested in:

- analyzing/comparing central tendency and variability
- identifying correlations
- identifying/explaining outliers
- identifying trends
- etc.